# PHP: how to generate this JSON?

Tags: php, json

I have an array `$a', includes the following data:

```
[0]=>'text',
[1]=>'text1, text2, text3'
```

I want to generate a JSON object from this data, as follow:

```
'{"TestingApplications": [
    { "ApplicationName": "text" },
    { "ApplicationName": "text1" },
    { "ApplicationName": "text2" },
    { "ApplicationName": "text3" }
  ]
}'
```

What I did:

```
<?php

$a=array(0=>"text", 1=>"text1, text2, text3");

$r = array();

foreach($a as $key => $val){

    if (strpos($val,',') !== false) {

        $v = explode(',', $val);

        foreach($v as $k => $l){

            array_push($r, $l);
        }
    } else{

        array_push($r, $val);
    }
}
```

So, how I can generate the required JSON using the data stored in `$r` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by creating the basic structure of the json object:

```
$temp = [
    'TestingApplications' => [],
];
```

Next, iterate over the data you have, and `explode` all of the comma-containing strings like you're doing right now:

```
foreach ($a as $value) {
    $exploded = explode(',', $value);//no need to check for comma's
    foreach ($exploded as $name) {
        //perhaps consider calling trim on $name here
        $temp['TestingApplications'][] = ['ApplicationName' => $name];
    }
}
```

Then finally, `json_encode` the lot:

```
return json_encode($temp);
```

Although truth be told: I'd really try to change the way the data is provided to my code. If all the string values should be treated the same way, it's totally unacceptable that sometimes, they're assigned to a distinct key (in the `$a` array), but that on other occasions, they're in a comma separated string.
This, to me at least, looks like an X-Y problem

Answer (score 1):

Try as below :

```
<?php
$a=array(0=>"text", 1=>"text1, text2, text3");

$r = array();$final = array();

foreach($a as $key => $val){

    if (strpos($val,',') >= 0) {

        $v = explode(',', $val);

        foreach($v as $k => $l){

            $r[]['ApplicationName']= "$l";
        }
    }
}
$final['TestingApplications'] = $r;

echo json_encode($final);
?>
```

Comment: `'{"ApplicationName": "'.$l.'"}'` Seriously: manually creating JSON strings, and then pass it to `json_encode`? this won't ever work

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem yeah right, this will cause a double stringified JSON object.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I have updated my answer. Please check now and thanks for your comments

Comment: @AnkiiG a couple more suggestions: 1) you're never going to add `text` to the applications array (because `$a[0]` does not contain a comma). 2) I'd replace `>= 0` with `!== false`. PHP implicitly casts values, `false` might be converted to int (`0`), in which case, if `strpos` returns false, the `if` might be evaluated to `0 >= 0`, in which case `test` _will_ be in the final array, but only because of a bug in the code. Lastly There's no point in quoting `$l` in `$r[]['ApplicationName']= "$l";`. Because you're calling `explode`, it's definitely a string. I would call `trim`, though

Answer (score 0):

You can try [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). This will returns the *JSON* representation of a value

For example:

```
$arr = array(0=>"text", 1=>"text1, text2, text3");
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Hope this help you well.

Answer (score 0):

json_encode(); is used to convert data in json from array in php.

```
$array = array('TestingApplications'=>array( "appname1"=>"text1","appname2"=>"text2", "appname3"=>"text3"));
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: `array( "appname1"=>"text1","appname1"=>"text2", ` <-- what do you think will happen if you're using the `appname1` key more than once in the same array?

Comment: I have edited my answer and by the way it is example for converting data in json format. Grab the idea and implement it

Comment: I already implemented this, and posted it as [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34761703/1230836) before you posted this. Just pointed out a bug in the snippet

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have this source:

```
$sourceArray = array(
    'text',
    'text1, text2, text3',
);
```

You need to build the right PHP array before you convert it to JSON. I propose to do so in a **recursive** way, while trimming the empty spaces too:

```
// get a flat array
$tmpArray = array_map(function($array) {
    return explode(',', $array);
}, $sourceArray);

$flatArray = array();
array_walk_recursive($tmpArray, function($a) use (&$flatArray) {
    $flatArray[] = trim($a);
});

$toJsonArray = array('TestingApplications' => array());
foreach ($flatArray as $val) {
    $toJsonArray['TestingApplications'][] = array(
        'ApplicationName' => $val,
    );
}
```

Then you just have to encode it to JSON:
`echo json_encode($toJsonArray);`

Answer (score 0):

To generate required JSON Object, array should be like following:

```
$arr = array(
'TestingApplications' => array(
    array('ApplicationName' => 'text'),
    array('ApplicationName' => 'text1'),
    array('ApplicationName' => 'text2'),
    array('ApplicationName' => 'text3'),
)
```

);

and then encode this array to json as: `echo json_encode($arr);` It will return required JSON Object

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$a=array(0=>"text", 1=>"text1,text2,text3");

$r = array();


    foreach($a as $key => $val){

        if (strpos($val,',') !== false) {

            $v = explode(',', $val);

            foreach($v as $k => $l){
                $final['ApplicationName']=$l;
                $final_arr[]=$final;
            }
        } else{
                $final['ApplicationName']=$val;
                $final_arr[]=$final;
        }
    }


    $result['TestingApplications']=$final_arr;
    echo json_encode($result);
```